# Add 1 only to Integers in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, integer

I have an array which contains mixed classes:

```
arr = ["I", "have", 2, "dimes", "and" , 3, "nickels"]
```

How do I perform addition on the integers in the array without modifying the strings?

The expected output is,

```
["I", "have", 3, "dimes", "and" , 4, "nickels"]
```

Comment: Jason, there is no rush in selecting an answer.  A quick-draw checkmark discourages other answers and is a discourtesy to those still preparing answers.  Also, you can do as you wish, but I would not upvote an answer whose author requested that I do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr.map!{|element| element.is_a?(Integer) ? element + 1 : element}`

Comment: Don't forget to upvote an answer. Also note that this solution modifies the existing an array, rather than returning a modified **copy** of the array.

Comment: I'm waiting for the 10 minute time limit to pass before accepting your answer!  And I need 15 reputation before I'm able to upvote!

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't realize there was a minimum time limit.

Comment: I don't think the "one liner" drum-roll is needed here.

Comment: Also, terser doesn't always mean better. I think using a do...end and an if...else over multiple lines would be much clearer.

Answer (score 7):

```
def add_to_integers(ary, n)
  ary.map { |i| i.is_a?(Integer) ? (i + n) : i }
end

add_to_integers([1, 'foo'], 1)
# => [2, "foo"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think `map` with `rescue` is appropriate since Strings respond to `+` and there are many numerical types.

```
arr.map { |n| begin; n + 1; rescue TypeError; n; end }
```

Comment: IMHO there is not need to raise such amount of exceptions when you can check if the element is an Integer or not.

Comment: Exceptions are not a problem, but his code also adds 1 to `Float` instances and all other objects that implement `#+` operators.

Comment: That implement `+` _with integers_, you mean. For example this would also work with complex numbers, rationals, etc. Not strictly what was asked for, but I think it's more duck-typish.